# rabbitmq-c on iOS devices doesn't work

Tags: ios, sockets, rabbitmq

I'm currently trying to use the rabbitmq-c library https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c on iOS. When I run my sample app on the iOS simulator, I'm able to open a socket using the *amqp_socket_open* . I basically get a *AMQP_STATUS_OK* return status from the call. However, when I run the same call on an iOS device, I get the *AMQP_STATUS_SOCKET_ERROR* error. I was wondering if anybody managed to open a socket through the rabbitmq-c library when run on an iOS device.

Thanks

JB

Comment: From what it looks like is that it's not supported for the arm architecture since it's not working on the iOS platform (and it works on the OSX platform). But I've heard people mentioning that it's supposed to work on the iOS paltform. would like to confirm that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. So I figured out what was wrong. The issue was that I was using "localhost" as the URI. Hence it was working on the simulator and not on device since the simulator was run on the same machine as the broker. Used a public URI instead and everything works. So rabbbitmq-c is supported on both OSX and iOS platform

Comment: Hi, I've compiled a static library using the newest version of rabbitmq-c using brew install directly, but I can only build it with OSX but not iOS. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Siyi, you'll have manually build rabbitmq-c on your machine using cmake and afterwards you'll need to manually select the rabbitmq headers and include it in your iOS project (along with the generated static library from cmake). Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed and built it using homebrew, but once I link the librabbitmq.a library in my iOS project, there is a compile error "ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/HEAD/lib/librabbitmq.dylib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). Any idea?

Comment: looks like you've built the static library of librabbitmq for the OSX architecture only. This doesnt include ARM architectures (which are used by iOS). You need to build the librabbitmq for the iOS architecture if your end target platform is iOS. In my case, I built it for both OSX and iOS.